# Not giving access to mdb file

Tags: asp.net, .net, ms-access, iis

I have a mdb file in d:rackelywin/rackely.mdb folder. rackelywin is shared folder which is used by other local computers. when I host the .net application in IIS it wont gives the permission to access the  rackel.mdb file. When i run the application locally it works.
please help me.

Comment: I think you have to copy that file into folder where .net application resides

Comment: I cant change the location of mdb which is updating continuously by other user which is locally connected.I also tried by copying .net application to shared folder that time it wont works.when i run the application  locally my application shows user as administrator. when i run in iis it wont shows any user. I think the problem is with permission...

Comment: @SatishDevadiga If the file is opened or someone is using at the time of Connection, then the process will never allow to access. If the problem because of permission then give the permissions to everyone and try.other wise you have to copy the file and locate some other folder.then do your process.

Comment: I made sure file is not opened any where.  If i copy the Mdb file into D: folder it works fine. D:  folder is not a shared folder but d:rackelywin/rackely.mdb  is a shared. In IIS application not running as administrator.

Comment: Can you please share what you did to solve this?

Comment: @SatishDevadiga share what you did to solve this, put your solution here. bcoz this question will be unanswered category so you just add your solution and mark it as answer. In future it will be helpful to some one.

Comment: The problem is with the permission of the folder. I changed the access rights to everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we need to change the permission of the shared folder.